# How to get the Teradata Server Health Status Log History

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Using Teradata viewpoint web page, I am able to see live Teradata server health status but I need to get the lost 10 days server health status.  I unable to get server helath status history using viewpoint. So please let me know how to get the Teradata server health status history using teradata viewpoint or log tables

Comment: The Productivity portlet shows System Health over the last 24 or 48 hours, and you can use the "Rewind" feature to back up to prior days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will check and get back to you if i have any other questions.